# Reorder position of NA's when using group_by

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, tibble

I would like to reorder the position of NA's in a column, within each level of another categorical variable. For example with this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(fact=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), id=rep(1:6), value=c(NA,44,23,NA,NA,76))
```

I would like to mutate a new column like:

```
df$newvar <= c(44,23,NA,76,NA,NA)
```

I would have thought the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
dfb <- df %>% group_by(fact) %>% mutate(newvar = df$value[order(is.na(df$value))])
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the `df$` part in your mutate statement, otherwise you are referring to the full column, instead of the column per group. So this should  work fine:

```
df %>% group_by(fact) %>% mutate(newvar = value[order(is.na(value))])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: fact [2]
   fact    id value newvar
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1.00     1  NA     44.0
2  1.00     2  44.0   23.0
3  1.00     3  23.0   NA  
4  2.00     4  NA     76.0
5  2.00     5  NA     NA  
6  2.00     6  76.0   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to use `dplyr` you can do this with base `R`:

```
df$newvar <- ave(df$value, df$fact, FUN = function(x) x[order(-x)])

df
#  fact id value newvar
#1    1  1    NA     44
#2    1  2    44     23
#3    1  3    23     NA
#4    2  4    NA     76
#5    2  5    NA     NA
#6    2  6    76     NA
```

Comment: I think `with(df, value[order(fact, -value)])` should also work based on the OP's example

Comment: @akrun, thats a good point. I'm inclined not to do that however, since as you implied, if `fact` wasn't already ordered it might give unexpected results

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to use `lead()` function to shift forward by the number of NAs in each group. i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(fact) %>% 
 mutate(new = lead(value, sum(is.na(value))))
```

which gives

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
> # Groups:   fact [2]
>    fact    id value   new
>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1  1.00     1  NA    44.0
> 2  1.00     2  44.0  23.0
> 3  1.00     3  23.0  NA  
> 4  2.00     4  NA    76.0
> 5  2.00     5  NA    NA  
> 6  2.00     6  76.0  NA
> ```

**NOTE:** This will only work If your NAs are at the top and you need them at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion, using `arrange` to be consistent with the dplyr verbs:

```
df %>%
  mutate(newvar = 
    arrange(df, fact, is.na(value), id) %>% pull(value)
  )
```

Comment: dplyr, like the OP

Comment: `pull` is available in versions >= 0.7.0 (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.7.0)